# Is it possible to pass in values for a list while executing groovy script

Tags: groovy

I have the below groovy script and it executes successfully this way I can pass in as many arguments needed to be verified against output of the command executed

```
 def outputString = task.in.text
 println "Output:  $outputString"
 def list = ['file/path/filename1', 'file/path/filename2']
 assert list.count{ i-> outputString.contains(i) } == list.size()
```

But I want to be able to pass in the list of values while executing the groovy script via command line. So I added an empty list (def list = []) and passed in the values to the list via command line like so

```
 groovyScript.groovy list = ['file/path/filename1', 'file/path/filename2']
```

But its returning an empty list using the code below to print the list

```
 def list = []
 String listAsString =  "[\"${list.join('", "')}\"]"
 println listAsString
```

returns the below was expecting it to print ['file/path/filename1', 'file/path/filename2']

```
 [""]
 Exit code: 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used the groovy cli option to resolve this issue. Below is the code for passing in the files list though cmd.

```
cli.files(longOpt:'files', args:1, required: false)

String files = cli.files
List<String> fileList = []
if (files != null){
  fileList.addAll(files.trim().split(',')) 
  println "${fileList}"
  assert fileList.count{ i-> outputString.contains(i) } == fileList.size()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you start your script like this:

```
groovy groovyScript.groovy "file/path/filename1" "file/path/filename2"
```

then in groovyScript.groovy you can take list of arguments by accessing `args` variable:

```
def list = args
...
```

Comment: thanks @daggett using cli option like stated below helped.